# Bootstrap CSS Issue: Align DIV to bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to lay out the 7-vs-5 row column as follows. The issue is that the DIV on the right needs to be pushed down on small displays, so that the dropdowns are aligned. The entire DIV can always be pushed down, not just the dropdown itself, because the label is guaranteed to always be short.

[image]

Structure:

```
<div class="question1">
   <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
      <!-- content: Label and field -->
   </div>
</div>

<div class="question2">
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
      <!-- content: Label and field -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Is there a quick way to achieve that?

Comment: There probably is a quick way, can you add the css too? I don't use bootstrap so can't see the rules that are already being applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It may work for you

```
<div class="question1">
   <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
      <!-- content: Label and field -->
   </div>
</div>

<div class="question2">
   <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
      <!-- content: Label and field -->
   </div>
</div>
```